# How to prevent duplicate values in a Dictionary in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dictionary where values are duplicating.

How do I prevent duplicates in dictionary?

This is my code:

```
private class GcellGtrx
{
    public Gcell Gcell { get; set; }
    public Gtrx Gtrx { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, GcellGtrx> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, GcellGtrx>();

dictionary.Add(gcell.CellId, gcellGtrx);
```

Comment: Is `CellId` something that should contain duplicates?

Comment: Yuval Itzchakov no that is unique

Comment: Then how is it possible that there are duplicate keys? How are you actually calling your code?

Comment: He said *values* are duplicating, not the keys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check duplicate key, you can use:

```
dictionary.ContainsKey(gcell.CellId);
```

and to check duplicate value, you can use:

```
dictionary.ContainsValue(gcellGtrx);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you can accept the overhead of scanning the entire dictionary for the possible duplicate, then this code will check if there's an existing value in the dictionary already:

```
dictionary.ContainsValue(gcellGtrx);
```

If you can't accept that, you should either:

- Create a dictionary with the two types in the opposite order, basically a dictionary from value to key
- Create a hashset of the values in the dictionary

Then it would be a similar lookup as you would do on a normal dictionary to see if the value is already present.

ie. you could do this:

```
private readonly Dictionary<int, GcellGtrx> _dictionary = new Dictionary<int, GcellGtrx>();
private readonly Dictionary<GcellGtrx, int> _reverseDictionary = new Dictionary<GcellGtrx, int>();

if (!_reverseDictionary.ContainsKey(gcellGtrx))
{
    _dictionary.Add(gcell.CellId, gcellGtrx);
    _reverseDictionary.Add(gcellGtrx, gcell.CellId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

either

```
_dictionary[gcell.CellId] = gcellGtrx;
```

this will have the last gcellGtrx in the dictionary.

OR

```
GcellCtrx testCell;

if (!_dictionary.TryGet(gcell.CellId, out testCell))
     _dictionary.Add(gcell.CellId, gcellGtrx);
```

This will keep the first gcellGtrx in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for duplicate values before adding to the dictionary:

```
if (!_dictionary.ContainsValue(gcellGtrx))
    _dictionary.Add(gcell.CellId, gcellGtrx);
```

**Update**

I edited my answer thanks to @Lasse V. Karlsen, who alerted me I misread the question.

Comment: He said that *values* are duplicating, not the keys. Basically he wants the dictionary to prevent duplicate values. Since a dictionary by itself only uses the keys for lookup, there's no built in functionality to handle this.